# spring security UserDetailsService with specific table Role

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-security, user-roles, userdetailsservice

I'm creating an app where I must use ***Spring Security login***. It's standard `login/logout`, and I found many tutorials how to create it. What is not standard - is a table role in Database. I can't change Database, I can just use it. I made right entities for user and role, but I can't get the way, how to write correctly `UserDetailsServiceImpl` with `loadUserByUsername`. I can't find even a close things...

Entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User implements model.Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", nullable = false)
    private Set<Role> roleId;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Set<Role> roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
 }
```

Role:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "role")
    public class Role implements model.Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "roleId", nullable = false)
    private int roleId;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private boolean user;

    @Column(name = "tutor")
    private boolean tutor;

    @Column(name = "admin")
    private boolean admin;

    public Role() {} // Empty constructor to have POJO class

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public boolean isUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(boolean user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isTutor() {
        return tutor;
    }

    public void setTutor(boolean tutor) {
        this.tutor = tutor;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role{" +
                "roleId=" + roleId +
                ", user='" + user + '\'' +
                ", tutor=" + tutor + '\'' +
                ", admin=" + admin +
                '}';
    }
}
```

So the main question is how to create realization of UserDetailServiceImpl which implements UserDetailsService:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ...
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        ...
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
```

Maybe I should create special class, which return the exact role of user.. Or maybe there is another ways?

I don't ask to code for me, just help say me how to make it better way of realization of such role. The main goal is to divide `Admin`, `Tutor` and `User`.

Comment: Your entity model is broken; it says there can be multiple role rows for same user; e.g. user can be admin in one row and not in another row.

Comment: @holmis83 yes it can be a multiple role for the same user. 
Why do you say, it's broken? Or you are talking about "ManyToMany" annotation?

Comment: Yes, the ManyToMany implies there can be contradicting rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I somehow agree with holmis83 comment, as in fact there could be some situations where `role` table could have strange (or at least, repeated and even contradicting) info in some combinations, there are a couple of ways you could take.

First of all, I suggest you to create a view in database to handle `role` table  in a way that it would be more `authorities-by-username-query` friendly

I would do it a kind this way:

```
SELECT roleId, 'ROLE_USER' as role FROM role WHERE user = 1
UNION
SELECT roleId, 'ROLE_TUTOR' as role FROM role WHERE tutor = 1
UNION
SELECT roleId, 'ROLE_ADMIN' as role FROM role WHERE admin = 1;
```

Just this way, for a database model like this

[image]

You will get this kind of results:

[image]

Now, you could make your `authorities-by-username-query` making an `inner join` from user with the newly created view instead of the original table.

```
SELECT user.login, roles_view.role FROM user as user 
INNER JOIN user_has_role as user_role ON user.userId = user_role.user_userId 
INNER JOIN roles_view ON user_role.role_roleId = roles_view.roleId
```

This would be the output:

```
username  |  role
----------------------
jlumietu  | ROLE_USER
jlumietu  | ROLE_ADMIN
username  | ROLE_USER
username  | ROLE_TUTOR
username  | ROLE_ADMIN
username  | ROLE_ADMIN
username  | ROLE_USER
username  | ROLE_TUTOR
username  | ROLE_ADMIN
username  | ROLE_TUTOR
```

As there could be some repeated info, you could make just a group by using username and role, just this way:

```
SELECT user.login, roles_view.role FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_has_role as user_role ON user.userId = user_role.user_userId 
INNER JOIN roles_view
ON user_role.role_roleId = roles_view.roleId 
GROUP BY login, role;
```

Just to get this results:

```
username  |  role
----------------------
jlumietu  | ROLE_ADMIN
jlumietu  | ROLE_USER
username  | ROLE_ADMIN
username  | ROLE_TUTOR
username  | ROLE_USER
```

In fact, it is not necessary to do this since spring security would handle it to avoid having repeated roles, but for purposes of readability if the query is manually executed I think it is well worth.

Once said this all, let's check the security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <security:http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/simple/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/simple/login.htm"
            authentication-failure-url="/simple/login.htm?error=true"
            default-target-url="/secured/home.htm"
            username-parameter="email" 
            password-parameter="password"
            login-processing-url="/secured/performLogin.htm" />

        <security:logout 
            logout-url="/secured/performLogout.htm"
            logout-success-url="/simple/login.htm" />

        <security:csrf disabled="true" />

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">

        <security:authentication-provider>      
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
            <security:jdbc-user-service id="jdbcUserService" data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
                    SELECT login AS username, password AS password, '1' AS enabled 
                    FROM user           
                    WHERE user.login=?" 
                authorities-by-username-query="
                    SELECT user.login, roles_view.role 
                    FROM user 
                    INNER JOIN user_has_role as user_role ON user.userId = user_role.user_userId 
                    INNER JOIN roles_view ON user_role.role_roleId = roles_view.roleId 
                    where user.login = ?
                    GROUP BY login, role"
            />          
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Even if you cannot create a view in database, you could manage to get it work just typing the select-union sql around your `role` table in the `authorities-by-username query`.

Note that with this workaround you do not need even to write a customized `UserDetailsService`

Comment: I'm made it in another way. I add in UserDetailService check: isAdmin isTutor isUser. If it's true, then userRole:ROLE_*
Now it is another combat.: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory.

If I'll fail, I'll try it your way.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, although my users can only have one role.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    final User user = Optional.ofNullable(findUserByEmail(username)).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User was not found"));
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRole());
    final boolean canLogin = user.isActive() && user.isVerified();
    if (!canLogin) {
        throw new AccountException("User is not enabled");
    }
    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(final Role userRole) {
    return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
}

private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(final User user, final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            authorities);
}
```

You could adapt getUserAuthority to something akin to:

```
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthorities(final Set<Role> roles) {
    return roles.stream().map(roleId -> {
        final Role role = roleRepository.findOne(roleId);
        if (role.isAdmin) {
            return new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");    
        } else if (role.isUser) {
            return new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        }
        // like wise for all your roles.
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```